# Type inference in lambdas

Tags: c#, generics, types, inference

I have this functionality:

```
 public class Repository : IRepository
    {
        public List<TEntity> GetOrdered<TEntity, TSortKey>(Func<TEntity, TSortKey> orderBy, int take, params string[] includePaths) where TEntity : AbstractEntity
        {
            var query = (from ent in this.Context.Set<TEntity>() select ent).IncludePaths(includePaths);

            return query.OrderBy(orderBy).Take(take).ToList();
        }
    }
```

To invoke it:

```
List<Project> p = repository.GetOrdered<Project, string>(x => x.Name, 10);
```

I want to eliminate the need to give it the second generic parameter when invoking, it's a deal breaker from an API perspective.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the compiler can infer all type parameters, or you have to specify them all. But you may explicitly specify the argument type of the lambda expression, such as:

```
List<Project> p = repository.GetOrdered((Project x) => x.Name, 10);
```

Comment: I didn't know I can do that with lambdas. Thank you! I don't like the usage syntax, but I guess it's the only possible way. This actually works.

Answer (score 3):

> it's a deal breaker from an API perspective

then consider your deal broken...  You can't partially infer generic parameters.  If your *repository* was generic you could possibly do:

```
 public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : AbstractEntity
{
    public List<TEntity> GetOrdered<TSortKey>(Func<TEntity, TSortKey> orderBy, int take, params string[] includePaths) 
    {
        var query = (from ent in this.Context.Set<TEntity>() select ent).IncludePaths(includePaths);

        return query.OrderBy(orderBy).Take(take).ToList();
    }
}
```

then do

```
List<Project> p = repository.GetOrdered(x => x.Name, 10);
```

But I don't know if that change is possible for you.

Comment: It is not generic, I like it better that way, I feel it allows simpler use. Thank you for the answer, I will +1 it, but take the other one, as it works within my architecture (albeit I don't like the usage syntax). And why don't they implement partial inference? It clearly makes sense, at least in this case.

Comment: @h.alex Because it costs money to design, build, test, and ship features.  The C# team weighs the benefit of a feature versus the cost, and weighs it against the benefit of other requested features.  So far it seems that the benefit isn't worth the cost. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6878596/1081897) for another opinion.

Comment: So MS should hire more architects, developers, and testers to build every single feature regardless of its value? Sorry, the world doesn't work that way.