# How to create a generic extension method with additional type for generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Today I encountered a small problem, and unfortunately I have not found a good solution. I would like to create a extension method for some generic interface. This method accepts a different type of a generic parameter, as seen below

```
public interface IGenericInterface<TSource>
{
    void DoSomething<TDest>();
}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DtZ9F6)

How to call a `DoSomething2` method exactly in the same way as `DoSomething` method (without passing first type)?

```
public void DoSomething<TDest>()
//Called like below
testClass.DoSomething<object>();
```

instead of (like my current signature)

```
public static void DoSomething2<TDest, TSource>(this IGenericInterface<TSource> interf)
//called like below
testClass.DoSomething2<string, object>(); // have to repass object type
```

I know that the compiler can not automatically infer the second type ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796896/c-sharp-generics-cant-infer-second-parameter)). But I'm curious if anyone has found a solution.

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code (as text) in your post.  The fiddles are great, but they are no substitute for actual code.  I've edited some of your code into your question.

Comment: That's not possible. In theory, c# could potentially infer the first type, but it either infers all type arguments or none, you can't have a partial infer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu thank you, i'll keep that in mind. Kenneth unfortunately, only such information come to me. It seems to me that there would be no problem if the compiler could infer the second type. In this case extension method it is hard to understand.

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve with this? It's quite possible there's a simpler, more idiomatic way to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the argument - you're depending on type inference to handle the first generic type, but then you want to explicitly specify the second one - that just isn't possible in C#.

Instead, why not change the type of the argument?

```
public static void DoSomething3<T, T2>(this IGenericInterface<T> interf, T2 parameter)
//called like below
testClass.DoSomething3((object)3);
```

With this, `T` is inferred based on `testClass` (as long as it's not ambiguous), and `T2` is inferred based on `(object)3`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not explicitly pass an object to this method. I fixed the content of the questions in order to better clarify this problem,

Comment: @PawelMaga Well, too bad. If you *really* want to avoid having to repeat the first argument, you could have a method like `DoSomething<T, T2>(this ..., T2 argument)`, with the argument only being there for type inference - you could then call `testClass.DoSomething3(default(object))` or `testClass.DoSomething3(default(string))`. You still need to know the proper type at runtime, of course.