# Infer second generic parameter based on the expression argument of the function

Tags: c#, generics

This question is an extension of 
[Partial type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003552/partial-type-inference)
If partial type inference is not possible, could anyone please explain how OrderByDescending extension method is working? Please note that when I call OrderByDescending(m=>m.DateProp), I am not asked to provide Type parameter.

```
static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByDescending<TSource, TKey>(
   this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
   Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector);
```

Comment: Well, it knows the `TSource` from `source`, and it knows `TKey` from the return type of your lambda - what do you think it's missing? Note that the question you linked is about supplying a partial set of types explicitly - you are supplying zero types explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

> could anyone please explain how OrderByDescending extension method is working?

I surely can.

```
static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByDescending<TSource, TKey>
(
  this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
  Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector);
```

When you call `foo.OrderByDescending( x => bar )` type inference proceeds as follows.

- First a set of bounds for `TSource` is inferred by examining `foo`.
- Then we ask "are there any more inferences we can make without knowing TSource?"  The answer is no, so we fix the value of `TSource` to the best member of the bound set.  Call it `S`.
- Then we ask "given the value of `TSource` is `S`, can we infer the value of `TKey`?  Yes.  We apply the type value `S` to `x`, and then infer the type of expression `bar` in an environment where `x` is of type `S`.
- The type of `bar` gives us the type for `TKey` and we're done.

> If partial type inference is not possible,...

Partial type inference is not *impossible*. Rather, it's not *implemented*. It's possible to add the feature to C#; no one has done it.

Regardless, whether or not inference from a partial set of bounds is implemented or possible, there's no difficulty in doing a complete inference of all the types in a call to `OrderByDescending`. Obviously we designed the algorithm specifically to be able to handle `OrderByDescending`, `Join` and so on.

Comment: Just go ahead and mark this as the answer, considering Eric helped design c#.